# breakline in javascript loop which makes buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function beggining1(){
        for (i=1;i<4;i++){
            for (j=1;j<4;j++){
                var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                btn.className = "button1";
                btn.id = i + j;
                var t = document.createTextNode(i+"_"+j);
                btn.appendChild(t);

                document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(btn);

            }



        }

    }
```

Ok so basically im doing buttons inside a div. Buttons have style :

```
.button1{
            background:green;
            height:50px;
            width:50px;
            margin:5px;

        }
```

but they are at the top of the div in one line i want everytime the second loop ends to do a breakline so button will position like square. I tried to

```
document.write('<br>');
```

after the second loop but it does not work any suggestions?

Comment: where you wrote document.write('<br>');

Comment: just after the end of the second loop after "document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(btn);

            }"

Comment: I wrote code below answers just use that instead of your document.write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
 document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML +'<br>';
```

Comment: jesus it worked but why , why  document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = '<br>'; didnt

Comment: Because we want to add <br> in div1 only not in document.

Answer (score 0):

try `document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML += '<br>';`

Comment: when i try this the buttons disappear